# Calculating worst-case run time complexity of algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am trying to work out the worst-case run time complexity for an algorithm i have created that checks if a given String is a cover string for a list of strings(for every string in a list, contains every strings characters within it, maintaining the left to right order).

Would i be correct in currently thinking that the worst-case run time complexity for this algorithm is O(N^2)? My logic is that for the inner for-loop which is executed n times, an if statement with complexity O(1) is called. And the outer loop is executed n times also, leading to t(n) of n*n or O(n^2).

```
public class StringProcessing {

//ArrayList created and 3 fields added.
public static ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
public static String list1 = "abc";
public static String list2 = "def";  
//public static String list3 = "fad"; 
//public static String list4 = "monkey";
//public static String list5 = "def";

//Boolean method to test whether a given string is a cover string for a single string.
//Method contains a for-each loop to iterate through characters of test String s.
public static boolean isSingleCover(String s, String cover)
{      
    int i = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray())
        if((i = cover.indexOf(c, i)) == -1)
            return false;
    return true;
}

//Second Boolean method to test whether a given string is a cover string for a given list of strings.
//The algorithm includes reference to the previous method for testing a single String, and uses this method
//for each string in the ArrayList.
public static boolean isCover(ArrayList<String> list, String cover)
{
    stringList.add(list1);
    stringList.add(list2);
    //stringList.add(list3);
    //stringList.add(list4);
    //stringList.add(list5);
    for(String s : list)
        if(!isSingleCover(s, cover))
            return false;
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(StringProcessing4.isCover(stringList, "adftyhgusbgusibadsjfksvgjchjgdkepf"));
}

}
```

Comment: This code is pretty confusing because you are mutating `stringList` - which is also `list`, because of how you call it from `main` - and then iterating through `list`. Why are you mutating `stringList` in `isCover` anyway?

Comment: You have to look for hidden loops when trying to determine complexity - think about how `indexOf` might be implemented.

Comment: @AndyTurner Knowing now that calling the indexOf function is actually not a constant time complexity, and should have the complexity O(n*m) where m in this instance will always be 1, as i am searching for chars, would the worst-case complexity actually be closer to O(n^3)?

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of Java's [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) of indexOf is O(m*n) where n and m are the length of the search string and pattern respectively.

So worst-case complexity O ( N * M * C), when N = stringList.size(), M = stringList.get(...).length() and C = cover.length()

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the information, would i then be right in assuming that O(N*M*C) is equivalent to O(N^3)? And that the complexity of the indexOf function would be O(n) as the length of the pattern i am looking for will always be 1 as i am searching for chars.

Comment: It's depends what your count. If we speak about function of summary chars in all string of stringList ( f(sum_chars_of_stringList) ) and cover.length = const , it's O(N). If you said I have N element in list, N element in cover and N element in every string of list -> it's O(N ^ 3). First of all, you need undesteand what you use as N.